# CSS | Bootstrap - Sidebar's blocks with dynamic height based content

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, styles, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to set the height of my sidebar's block that must be stretched/filled with the sidebar main block. Also my sidebar block must be the same height of the content block.

Here an image of example that I've made:

[image]

I'm using bootstrap 4 and I've tried with grid/flexbox and position relative/absolute (sidebar position absolute and container position relative) but when i try set a percentage height on blocks they didn't respect that.

How can be done?

Here the last example of what I've tried to do then with the position relative and absolute (the original code is in php)

```
<div class="row position-relative">
       <div class="col-md-3 p-0"></div>
       <div class="col-md-3 p-0 position-absolute h-100">
           <div class="d-none d-md-block">
            <div id="boxsubmenu">
              <div class="level_0">

BLOCK 1 <-----
                  <a href="{CATALOG_LINK}" class="level_0">{TPL_LAN.LBL_CAT_MENU_TITLE}{MENU4.LABEL}</a>
                  <div>
                    <div class="level_{MENU.LEVEL} {MENU.SELECTED} {MENU.LAST}">
                      <a href="{MENU.LINK}" class="{MENU.SELECTED}">{MENU.LABEL}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="level_{MENU.LEVEL} {MENU.SELECTED} {MENU.LAST}">
                      <a href="{MENU.LINK}" class="{MENU.SELECTED}">{MENU.LABEL}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="level_{MENU.LEVEL} {MENU.SELECTED} {MENU.LAST}">
                      <a href="{MENU.LINK}" class="{MENU.SELECTED}">{MENU.LABEL}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="level_{MENU.LEVEL} {MENU.SELECTED} {MENU.LAST}">
                      <a href="{MENU.LINK}" class="{MENU.SELECTED}">{MENU.LABEL}</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
BLOCK 2 <-----
                  <a href="{CATALOG_LINK}" class="level_0">{TPL_LAN.LBL_CAT_MENU_TITLE}{MENU4.LABEL}</a>
                  <div>
                    <div class="level_{MENU.LEVEL} {MENU.SELECTED} {MENU.LAST}">
                      <a href="{MENU.LINK}" class="{MENU.SELECTED}">{MENU.LABEL}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="level_{MENU.LEVEL} {MENU.SELECTED} {MENU.LAST}">
                      <a href="{MENU.LINK}" class="{MENU.SELECTED}">{MENU.LABEL}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="level_{MENU.LEVEL} {MENU.SELECTED} {MENU.LAST}">
                      <a href="{MENU.LINK}" class="{MENU.SELECTED}">{MENU.LABEL}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="level_{MENU.LEVEL} {MENU.SELECTED} {MENU.LAST}">
                      <a href="{MENU.LINK}" class="{MENU.SELECTED}">{MENU.LABEL}</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>

BLOCK 3 <-----
                  <a href="{CATALOG_LINK}" class="level_0">{TPL_LAN.LBL_CAT_MENU_TITLE}{MENU4.LABEL}</a>
                  <div>
                    <div class="level_{MENU.LEVEL} {MENU.SELECTED} {MENU.LAST}">
                      <a href="{MENU.LINK}" class="{MENU.SELECTED}">{MENU.LABEL}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="level_{MENU.LEVEL} {MENU.SELECTED} {MENU.LAST}">
                      <a href="{MENU.LINK}" class="{MENU.SELECTED}">{MENU.LABEL}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="level_{MENU.LEVEL} {MENU.SELECTED} {MENU.LAST}">
                      <a href="{MENU.LINK}" class="{MENU.SELECTED}">{MENU.LABEL}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="level_{MENU.LEVEL} {MENU.SELECTED} {MENU.LAST}">
                      <a href="{MENU.LINK}" class="{MENU.SELECTED}">{MENU.LABEL}</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-9">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-xs-12 p-5 col-md-9" style="width: 100% !important;">
                   {PAGE_CONTENT}
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Please post your current code within your question.

Comment: @WebDevBooster the code is inside multiple php/css file and is too large to post in my opinion but I can try to insert an extract wait

Comment: In this case, you should read the following page before doing anything: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic layout can be achieved with flexbox:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-col {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

.right-col {
  width: 70%;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-col border">
  <div class="box border"></div>
  <div class="box border"></div>
  <div class="box border"></div>
</div>

<div class="right-col border"></div>
```

Comment: This is certainly one way of doing it, yes. However, this solution ignores the tools/classes that are already provided by Bootstrap to do this job. In other words, the use of Bootstrap becomes pretty pointless at this point.

Comment: It always amazes me at how many people on here are very critical but don't offer anything themselves, by all means, show us how it is done using bootstrap

Comment: Since this answer has already been accepted, I don't see any need for me to post another one. But hey, the OP can always post another question if he needs a responsive version without adding more css. :-)

Comment: Because the OP can always change their minds and go for a better answer that uses their tech, I've done it on a few questions where I've thought of a different way that adds to the site - it also offers future readers an alternate way

Comment: Nah, the OP shall post another question if he needs a different solution.

Comment: I've used the bootstrap classes but the flex-basis isn't in the documentation then I've added it manually on css file. Ty @Pete i didn't known flex-basis